# How to unscope joins in RoR 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, default-scope, active-record-query

Trying to unscope joins.

Example:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> { joins("JOIN other_table ON other_table.this_table_id = this_table.id") }
  scope :without_relation -> { unscope(:joins) }
end
```

The problem is that it unscope ALL joins, even those that are automatically constructed by AR relations.

Comment: Did you tried changing the name to some other name other than `joins` ? That may be the cause I guess.

Comment: Huh? `:joins` is a defined value for `uncope`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/10d0c43c7937f65b2fc6fb87a87b1023bbd85674/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L346

Comment: Wow. Can't you just define a named scope with a relatively short identifier and not use it when you don't need it? Well, this is not really a question, more like info for consideration.

Comment: @D-side the thing is I don't need it in few cases. And the codebase is already too large.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
module UnscopeJoins
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def unscope_joins(joins_string)
    joins_values.reject! {|val| val == joins_string}
    self
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Relation.send :include, UnscopeJoins
```

Usage:

```
scope :without_joins, -> { unscope_joins("JOIN table on table2.id = table1.table2_id") }
```